# How do I calculate average hours in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I get a field in SQL format hours, I need to average these hours, how can I do this?
I tried to convert to seconds, but do not know how to proceed with this raciocionio.

I tried using SUM but also was not accepted by SSRS, because it does not allow the function inside;

SSRS 2008

Comment: And a data sample + the expected output. Please.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it may be your syntax because SSRS should accept the sum function.  See link.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255275.aspx
Can you include your sql code?